# Why doesn't nodeChanged call trigger the cellrenderer of the given Node to be executed in a Jtree?

Tags: java, swing, jtree

I have an application where the JTree nodes contain JProgressBars. I use a function like this to update the UI for the given node:

```
public void setProgressForNode(DefaultMutableTreeNode node, int progressValue)
{
    ((ExecutionItem) node.getUserObject()).setProgressValue(progressValue);
    originalModel.nodeChanged(node);
}
```

This function is called whenever the node that holds the progressbar should be updated to the given value. `nodeChanged(node)` should update the UI but it doesn't. Anyone has idea?
What I can see is the renderer is not called for the given node after calling `nodeChanged(node)`. *If I click the node in the tree continually during the "execution" progress the renderer is called so that the progressbar updates.*

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

if im not mistaken there is a Invalidate in most object in C# and Java 
In my experience that is the one to use then you want to redraw a control/object like procesbars.

if it is postible it is maybe something like this:

```
Node.Invalidate()
```

that should force a redraw of the ui no matter what its doing
Good luck to ya

Comment: It is far away from JAVA concept. Java is using models so invalidate, repaint, etc shouldn't be called to trigger changes in the tree itself.
What's more it doesn't work...

Comment: im sorry for that, it worked for me then i was working with a progres bar that would update its progress. figured the same thing  could be wrong here. well it was worth a shoot.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the below;

```
DefaultMutableTreeNode parent = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) node.getParent();
originalModel.nodeStructureChanged(parent);
```

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work :( What's more the parent here is the root which is not the best to update because the whole tree will be updated isn't it?